# Mapping a column of a table to different class using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Is there a way to specify a different table for a column?

For example, if there is a class "A" and another class "B":

Class A has a column called `col` and it actually is a foreign key to class B. Class B does not have any foreign key for A.

How can I define class A so that `col` of table A actually maps to the ID of table/class B?

Comment: what do you mean `maps` to ID of table B?

Comment: I mean table B has a column called ID and column col of A is actually a foreign key to B, hence its basically refering to column ID of B. Ideally instead of having col, its name should have been B_ID. But I can't change the table schema, hence need to somehow map col to B's ID.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rails [belongs_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to) has a `foreign_key` option:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :b, :foreign_key => :col
end
```

Comment: I would like to note that while this answers the OPs question, it's not the "rails way" and doing so is fighting against the framework.  Unless the OP cannot modify the tables, he should refactor to let ActiveRecord manage the foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a new table, you can achieve this via a migration also.

Add this line to your migration:

```
t.references :A, index: true
```

By default this will create `B_id` in table A.